# How to compare 2 successive row values in a resultset object using python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table `issue_logs`:

```
 id | issue_id | from_status | to_status |             up_date              |  remarks  
----+----------+-------------+-----------+----------------------------------+-----------
 29 |       20 |          10 |        11 | 2018-09-14 11:43:13.907052+05:30 | UPDATED
 28 |       20 |           9 |        10 | 2018-09-14 11:42:59.612728+05:30 | UPDATED
 27 |       20 |             |         9 | 2018-09-11 17:45:35.13891+05:30  | NEW issue
 26 |       19 |           9 |        11 | 2018-09-06 16:37:05.935588+05:30 | UPDATED
 25 |       19 |             |         9 | 2018-09-06 16:27:40.543001+05:30 | NEW issue
 24 |       18 |          11 |        10 | 2018-09-05 17:13:37.568762+05:30 | UPDATED
```

and `rt_status`:

```
 id |   description    | duration_in_min 
----+------------------+-----------------
  1 | new              |               1
  2 | working          |               1
  3 | approval pending |               1
  4 | resolved         |               1
  5 | initial check    |               1
  6 | parts purchase   |               1
  7 | shipment         |               1
  8 | close            |               1
  9 | initial check    |               1
 10 | parts purchase   |               1
 11 | shipment         |               1
 12 | close            |               1
```

For a date range `from_datetime = '2018-09-06T16:34'` to `to_datetime = '2018-09-14T12:27'` I want to select all the issues that have exceeded the `duration_of_time` set for each status value defined in the `rt_status` table. I should get from issue logs the records with ids 29, 27, and 26. The records with ids 29, and 26 should consider the time elapsed between their last `up_date` and `to_datetime`.

I would like to use the `func.lag` and `over` to do it, but I'm unable to get the correct records. I am using Postgresql 9.6, and Python 2.7. How exactly can I get the `func.lag` or `func.lead` to work using **SQLAlchemy Core** only?

What I tried:

```
    s = select([
            rt_issues.c.id.label('rtissue_id'),
            rt_issues,
            rt_status.c.duration_in_min,
            rt_status.c.id.label('stage_id'),
            issue_status_logs.c.id.label('issue_log_id'),
            issue_status_logs.c.up_date.label('iss_log_update'),
            (issue_status_logs.c.up_date - func.lag(
                    issue_status_logs.c.up_date).over(
                    issue_status_logs.c.issue_id
                    )).label('mdiff'),
            ]).\
    where(and_(*conditions)).\
    select_from(rt_issues.
    outerjoin(issue_status_logs,
              rt_issues.c.id == issue_status_logs.c.issue_id).
    outerjoin(rt_status,
              issue_status_logs.c.to_status == rt_status.c.id)).\
    order_by(asc(issue_status_logs.c.up_date),
                  issue_status_logs.c.issue_id).\
    group_by(
             issue_status_logs.c.issue_id,
             rt_issues.c.id,
             issue_status_logs.c.id
             )
    rs = g.conn.execute(s)
    mcnt =  rs.rowcount
    print mcnt, 'rowcont'
    if rs.rowcount > 0:
        for r in rs:
            print dict(r)
```

This yields results that include wrong records, i.e. issue log with id 28. Can anyone help with rectifying the error?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%c3%a4 I have reduced the code, please check if you can help

Comment: Also on row 24 the status seems to go backwards. Is that by design or mistake?

Comment: @IljaEverilä 24, 25 I was perhaps concentrating on issue id 20, 19 only...ignored 24, 25. Sorry my mistake. I was able to rectify the problem finally. Will post the solution shortly

Comment: Also my bad: did not notice that records 24 and 25 are filtered out by your `from_datetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution with modified sqlalchemy expression language:

```
s = select([
        rt_issues.c.id.label('rtissue_id'),
        rt_issues.c.title,
        rt_status.c.duration_in_min,
        rt_status.c.is_last_status,
        rt_status.c.id.label('stage_id'),
        issue_status_logs.c.id.label('issue_log_id'),
        issue_status_logs.c.up_date.label('iss_log_update'),
        (issue_status_logs.c.up_date - func.lag(
                issue_status_logs.c.up_date).over(
                issue_status_logs.c.issue_id)).
        label('mdiff'),
        (func.lead(
                issue_status_logs.c.issue_id).over(
                issue_status_logs.c.issue_id
                )).label('next_id'),
        (func.lead(
                issue_status_logs.c.up_date).over(
                issue_status_logs.c.issue_id,
                issue_status_logs.c.up_date,
                )).label('prev_up_date'),
        issue_status_logs.c.user_id,
        (users.c.first_name + ' ' + users.c.last_name).
        label('updated_by_user'),
        ]).\
    where(and_(*conditions)).\
    select_from(rt_issues.
    outerjoin(issue_status_logs,
              rt_issues.c.id == issue_status_logs.c.issue_id).
    outerjoin(users, issue_status_logs.c.user_id == users.c.id).
    outerjoin(rt_status,
              issue_status_logs.c.to_status == rt_status.c.id)).\
    order_by(issue_status_logs.c.issue_id,
             asc(issue_status_logs.c.up_date)).\
    group_by(
             issue_status_logs.c.issue_id,
             rt_issues.c.id,
             issue_status_logs.c.id,
             rt_status.c.id,
             users.c.id
             )
rs = g.conn.execute(s)
if rs.rowcount > 0:
    for r in rs:
        # IMPT: For issue with no last status
        if not r[rt_status.c.is_last_status]:
            if not r['mdiff'] and (not r['next_id']):
                n = (mto_dt - r['iss_log_update'].replace(tzinfo=None))
            elif ((not r['mdiff']) and
                  (r['next_id'] == r['rtissue_id'])):
                n = (r['prev_up_date'] - r['iss_log_update'])
            else:
                n = (r['mdiff'])
            n =  (n.total_seconds()/60)
            if n > r[rt_status.c.duration_in_min]:
                mx = dict(r)
                q_user_wise_pendency_list.append(mx)

    for t in q_user_wise_pendency_list:
        if not t in temp_list:
            temp_list.append(t)
    q_user_wise_pendency_list = temp_list
```

Comment: This solution has some nondeterministic behaviour, I think: for example `func.lag(issue_status_logs.c.up_date).over(issue_status_logs.c.issue_id)` does not define an ordering, so as far as I understand it is unspecified what row the lagged value is from. It may seem to work now, but you cannot trust that it produces the same answers even for successive queries.

Comment: @IljaEverilä, I think you are right, changing above: func.lag(issue_status_logs.c.up_date).over(issue_status_logs.c.issue_id, issue_status_logs.c.up_date)  solve the problem ?

Comment: That'll have deterministic results, at least to my understanding.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I will let you know when I use above with large data. Thank you for pointing out the drawback

Answer (score 1):

Though you yourself managed to solve your question, here's one take on it that does not use window functions, namely `lag()` or `lead()`. In order to compare differences between the `up_date` timestamps of consecutive issue logs you could self left join. In SQL the query could look like

```sql
select    ilx.id
from      issue_logs ilx
join      rt_status rsx on rsx.id = ilx.to_status
left join issue_logs ily on  ily.from_status = ilx.to_status
                         and ily.issue_id = ilx.issue_id
where     ilx.up_date >= '2018-09-06T16:34'
and       ilx.up_date <= ( coalesce(ily.up_date, '2018-09-14T12:27') -
                           interval '1 minute' * rsx.duration_in_min );
```

and the same in SQLAlchemy [SQL Expression Language](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html):

```
from_datetime = '2018-09-06T16:34'
to_datetime = '2018-09-14T12:27'

ilx = issue_status_logs.alias()
ily = issue_status_logs.alias()
rsx = rt_status

query = select([ilx.c.id]).\
    select_from(
        ilx.
        join(rsx, rsx.c.id == ilx.c.to_status).
        outerjoin(ily, and_(ily.c.from_status == ilx.c.to_status,
                            ily.c.issue_id == ilx.c.issue_id))).\
    where(and_(ilx.c.up_date >= from_datetime,
               ilx.c.up_date <= (func.coalesce(ily.c.up_date, to_datetime) -
                                 cast('1 minute', Interval) *
                                 rsx.c.duration_in_min)))
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2681632/ilja-everil%c3%a4 Thank you for the trouble of providing the above solution. I have posted  my version of the solution below, but don't know how to undelete it.

Comment: Your previous answer was deleted by a moderator due to not actually being an answer (originally), and can only be undeleted by a moderator. If you want to post your own solution, just create another answer, if possible.