# Translating query with lag function to sqlalchemy with flask?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to translate the following query to sqlAlchemy and can't seem to figure it out (I'm not even far yet):

```
    "SELECT time, version_id FROM ( \
    SELECT \
    time, \
    version_id, \
    LAG(software_version_id) OVER (ORDER BY time) as previous_version_id \
    FROM device_checkins WHERE device_id = 001 AND time BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-04-01') tt \
    WHERE previous_version_id IS NULL OR version_id != previous_version_id;"
```

As far as I could figure out, I need the `select` function that sqlAlchemy provides but I'm running into trouble.

Of course, in the python representation, we have a `DeviceCheckin` model with all the fields that are used here. I'd love all the help you might be able to provide.

```
class DeviceCheckin(ModelBase):
    __tablename__ = "device_checkins"
    time = db.Column(DateTimeUtc(), nullable=False)
    device_id = db.Column(sa.BigInteger, nullable=False)
    device = db.relationship(...)

    software_version_id = db.Column(...)
    software_version = db.relationship(...)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what issues did you get. Can you also please add your model!

Comment: I've added the model. I'm currently slowly tiptoeing around the problem trying to make it work as a textual sql query first. I've also experimented with the mentioned select statement and looked a solutions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52330925/how-to-compare-2-successive-row-values-in-a-resultset-object-using-python

Comment: However, I've had some problems working in the subquery in the select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw up the subquery expression as follows:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
#...
entities = [
    DeviceCheckin.time,
    DeviceCheckin.version_id, 
    sa.func.lag(
        DeviceCheckin.software_version_id
    ).over(
        order_by=DeviceChecking.time
    ).label('previous_version_id')
]
condition = (
    (DeviceCheckin.device_id == '001') 
    & (DeviceCheckin.time.between('2020-01-01', '2021-04-01'))
)

subq = DeviceCheckin.query.with_entities(entities).filter(condition).subquery()
```

Then select from it in the following manner:

```py
condition = (
    subq.c.previous_version_id.is_(None) 
    | (subq.c.version_id != subq.c.previous_version_id)
)
entities = [subq.c.time, subq.c.version_id]

query = subq.select(entities).where(condition)

results = db.session.execute(query)
```